Is it possible to disable room boundary system of Meta Quest devices?
I'm currently in the stage of deciding my target platform for a small project. In the broadest sense, I'm looking for a device that can track the position of its user in a large and complex space. One possibility is the Meta Quest, as it lets its users freely roam around in a room. What I want, however, is to disable the guardian/play-space feature of the Quest as the physical scale of the project is much too large for the supported scale of the guardian feature.
I've found that it can be turned off visually, that it can be turned off when tracking is off as well, but I would like to roam around the building and have the headset keep tracking me. Basically, I want to create an AR app where the user can go up and down the stairs and explore a space, while I am showing them stuff.

You know if you do that you risk them falling down the stairs or over a railing?  I mean if you want to be responsible for them when they are out of the safety grid ...

@easleyfixed This isn't for a commercial application, the users will be monitored during their usage of the app. This is not a major concern for my use case
